# How to search only part of a text string?

Tags: string, search, limit

I'm sorry if this question is too basic. Really a newb here.

In a database with many rows full of text I would like to have a query to find any rows with the word 'thunder' in the first 100 characters but ignore any that don't have it or have it past 100 characters. So, for example, I have a text field:

*When shall we three meet again? 
In thunder, lightning, or in rain?
When the hurlyburly's done, 
When the battle's lost and won.*

In the above I'd expect a row like this to trigger. Something like

SELECT FROM table1 WHERE field1 LIKE '%thunder%' AND search_only_first_chars = 100;

Thanks guys, sorry if this is so easy it made your eyes roll!

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Tag your question with the DB you're using

Answer (score 1):

This should work in general:

```
select from table1 where left(field1, 100) like '%thunder%'
```

To the best of my knowledge, `LEFT` and its counterpart `RIGHT` will give you the N leftmost (or rightmost) characters of a text value on SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.